# Conditional expectation between lognormal random variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

My question is whether the conditional expectation between lognormal random variables $Y$ and $X$, i.e $\mathbb{E}(Y|X)$ has a closed form linear (or non-linear) expression similar to Gaussian random variables. Recall that if $(Z,W)$ are jointly normal, then $\mathbb{E}(Z|W)=\beta_0 +\beta_1W$, where $\beta_0=\mathbb{E}(Z)-\beta_1\mathbb{E}(W)$ and $\beta_1=\frac{Cov(Z,W)}{Var(W)}$.

Can we use this result by transforming lognormals to normals and then after using the result for normals, transform it back to logs?

Comment: Are you assuming that $\log (X)$ and $\log(Y)$ are jointly normal?

Comment: I haven't thought about that, but I believe yes. If i have two normals, then they should be jointly normal because any linear combination gives me a normal by reproducing property of the normals, right?

Comment: Actually no, and that's the tricky part. The classic counterexample is: take $U$ a normal random variable, and define $V := U \cdot (2B-1)$, with $B$ a Bernoulli$\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)$. You can show that $V$ is also normal, but $U+V$ is most certainly not as it has a $\frac{1}{2}$ probability of being $0$. Look for "copulas" for other examples in this vein where each marginal distribution is normal. The "jointly normal" case is a rare thing among the possibilities

Comment: These three assertions are true: 1: Any linear combinations of a pair of jointly normal variables is normal. 2: Two independent normal variables are jointly normal. 3: Two normal variables are not necessarily jointly normal. I assume your textbook assumes either joint normality or independence (which implies joint normality)

Comment: I see, yes, that makes perfect sense. I missed independence or joint normality assumption. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that we have
$$X=e^{\mu_X+\sigma_XZ_1},\,Y=e^{\mu_Y+\sigma_Y\rho Z_1+\sigma_Y\sqrt{1-\rho^2}Z_2}$$
where $Z_1,Z_2\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ are independent, $\mu_X,\mu_Y\in \mathbb{R}$, $\sigma_X,\sigma_Y>0$ and $\rho \in (-1,1)$. Then $\ln(X)\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_X,\sigma_X^2)$, $\ln(Y)\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_Y,\sigma_Y^2)$ and $\textrm{Cov}[\ln(X),\ln(Y)]=\sigma_X\sigma_Y\rho$. Also note that
$$Z_1=\frac{\ln(X)-\mu_X}{\sigma_X}$$
So we can write, thanks to the independence of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ and the fact that $X=f(Z_1)$ is independent of $Z_2$,
$$\begin{aligned}E[Y|X]&=E[e^{\sigma_Y\sqrt{1-\rho^2}Z_2}]e^{\mu_Y+\frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_X}\rho (\ln(X)-\mu_X)}=\\
&=e^{\frac{1}{2}\sigma_Y^2(1-\rho^2)+\mu_Y+\frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_X}\rho (\ln(X)-\mu_X)}\end{aligned}$$

Comment: @DavidMark this is just a standard modelling scenario (esp. in finance) in which we can find the closed form of $E[Y|X]$ easily because of how we constructed the joint distribution of $\ln(X),\ln(Y)$. I am not aware of general results of that kind for the multivariate lognormal distribution.

Comment: do you have any references? A textbook or whatever to get more details on that? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @DavidMark have a look at [this](https://www.amazon.it/Quantitative-Risk-Management-Concepts-Techniques/dp/0691166277) for a standard reference on (log)normal financial modelling.